# Do have anyone ajax tools(packages) in node.js express? to link(post/get) other server and get back data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I went to using ajax in node.js to get/post JSON data other server and get back JSON data, how to I do this? Do have anyone package can be doing this? Like to the jQuery `$.ajax`, `$.post` or `$.get` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is [npm package request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) you can use it like

```
var request = require('request');

request('http://json-sending-url.com', function(error, response, body) { 
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var json = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(json);
  } else {
    console.error(error);
    console.error(response);
  }
});
```

Comment: how to set the get parameter in request, ex: http://json-sending-url.com?para_a=123&para_b=234, how to set para_a and para_b parameter?

Comment: I think you can pass it as it is if it does not work try `request({ url: yourUrl qs:  querStringAsHash })` where `querStringAsHash= { param_a: 123, param_b:234  }`

Comment: I can rewrite this? ex:    request({ url: yourUrl qs: querStringAsHash },function(error, response, body) { //there is get back data?  });

Comment: yes you can read more here https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Comment: how to set the request() synchronize request , like jquery $.ajax set async: false, I can not find the set explanation.

Comment: generally sync is bad but have look at this https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/sync-request

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple library `HTTP` that come with node.js
or these libraries.

```
   Request https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

   Superagent http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/
```

Comment: the Request is good package!